# vba code to insert dynamic amt of rows

Tags: vba, dynamic, insert

need to modify this code which currently pastes the current region to the specified page, to instead read the # of rows used on the sheet that is called, and then insert that number of rows before pasting the data. having issues if the sheet called is > 187 rows it will paste over existing data that it should not touch. need it to then reset when a new sheet is called to the pasting area

```
    Dim wkSht As Worksheet

For Each wkSht In Sheets
'sheet6 is the DashboardMain sheet

    If Sheet6.Range("E3").Value = wkSht.Name Then
    wkSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Sheet6.Range("A12")

    End If


Next
```

Comment: Do you mean, if the current range is greater than 187 rows? Also, where is the pasting area?

Comment: the pasting area is on sheet 6 located in the range A12:T199. my data table needs not to be touched starts on row 200. so the pasting area is effectively 187 rows. currently all my sheets (that are called to pasting area) are less than 187 rows but that will change and I need to accommodate a dynamic # of rows value for each sheet that is called

Comment: Do you want the "old" data to be cleared when new data is pasted in?  If you need to paste more than 187 rows, then you table starting in row 200, will not be able to stay in row 200, can it move?

Comment: yes. that would be ideal

Comment: moving the table is an option. although it would require I change all my current working macros to accommodate new positioning of the table. I thought it would be much more efficient to make the pasting area dynamic. maybe by default it would show 20 or so blank rows, and then when a sheet is called it would insert x num of rows and move the table down, then moving it back when a new sheet is called

Comment: This will get you the number of rows in the data you are copying.  wkSht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Comment: to be more specific, I have a macro that reads the table and returns search results, and at the end of that macro it then calls the corresponding sheet name, so as long as the table is in row 200 to start with, it can move later, then needs to be placed back where it was

Comment: why does the table have to be placed back?  You can access its location and reference its contents easily even if it moves.

Comment: @QHarr to answer your question, my table is referenced in several other macros as absolute cell locations. my vba knowledge is limited on how to make those references dynamic if the table were to move...